# checking FLS in triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, security

I've seen loads of code examples of triggers and helper classes. They never check for object or field level permissions. I wonder if this was done for code clarity or is this something

1. one does only in controllers and assumes all trigger's code should execute in system mode Or
2. is this a poor coding skills just like writing 1 line unit tests?
3. What is the industry's practice?
4. Would a certification panel fail you for not checking an object permissions?

Comment: I might have to be corrected but triggers run in the system context (another reason why minimal logic should be in them)  and classes run with sharing by default. Now I presume the latter includes FLS. This link may help: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Comment: @Girbot: When we use `Handler classes` in triggers, they can be used `with sharing` I believe. What about them in that case?

Comment: you are a bit confused. With sharing affects only the subset of records you work on not CRUD and FLS. "All Apex code runs in system mode, where the permissions and record sharing of the current user are not taken into account. System method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s record sharing is enforced. The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing." you can delete a record in apex even if profile has do delete access on object & schema isDeletable() = false

Comment: **All Apex code runs in system mode, where the permissions and record sharing of the current user are not taken into account** That's only true if everything you are running explicitly says **without sharing** which is definitely not a best practice.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you do need to check CRUD/FLS in triggers.

There are several misconceptions about sharing, CRUD/FLS, and triggers in the responses to this question. To clarify:

1) Sharing (record level access or visibility of a *particular* record) has nothing to do with FLS (field level access to a field on all records)  They are orthogonal. FLS answers "is the current user allowed modify addresses of Accounts?", whereas sharing answers "which accounts can the user modify". Both need to be checked, and checking one does not substitute for checking the other. You need to check whether the user is allowed to modify the addresses of accounts in general *and* know whether the user is allowed to modify this particular account (whether this account is 'shared' with the user). This is why you need to make both checks. Unfortunately the platform's 'with sharing' keyword only handles whether the record is accessible and does not tell you whether a particular field on that record is accessible. Similarly, a salesperson profile may be such that they can read leads, but if the sharing policy for leads is such that only the owner of a lead can view that lead, and if the user doesn't own any leads, then they won't be able to view any leads. Enforcement of sharing is not the same as enforcement of CRUD, and it's not the same as enforcement of FLS (which determines access to a particular field on Lead)

2) Both Apex Classes and Triggers run in system mode by default. This is *why* you need to check permissions in your code. Running in system mode is not a reason to avoid checking permissions.

3) To expound on 2), it is not true that classes respect the user's permissions unless they are explicitly 'without sharing'. 'Without sharing' is the default and an explicit 'with sharing' is needed, but  this only enforces record access but not field accesses. Actually the situation is a bit more complicated -- if one class invokes a method in an instance of another class, and the invoked class omits the sharing declaration, then it inherits the sharing declaration of the caller. But still the default sharing mode is 'without sharing'. In addition to this, even if your code is running without sharing, you still need to check for CRUD/FLS manually. CRUD/FLS checks work just fine in triggers as they do in async apex such as scheduled jobs.

4) Unlike Apex classes, you cannot use the 'with sharing' keyword on triggers. That does not mean that triggers do not have an associated user context that can be queried for permissions -- they do. All actions on the platform are performed with an associated user context that can be queried in Apex for both record level access and field level access.

You can and should do CRUD/FLS checks in triggers just as in all other classes, and must make sure that record access is still enforced by your code even if your code is running in a trigger.

Now in some cases, record access is obvious in a trigger -- for example, if you have a trigger on update of an object and the trigger changes another field of the same object, then as long as the rest of your code respects user permissions, the trigger wouldn't be called if the user didn't have record level access to that object in the first place.  So checking for sharing within triggers is redundant in many cases, but that doesn't mean that your code can override the organization's policies. Also, checking for CRUD/FLS is generally not redundant and still needs to be performed, either in the trigger itself or in the trigger handler.

However if the trigger modifies a different object then it's no longer obvious that the user has record access to that object and so you do need to make the record access check as well as the CRUD/FLS check.

One way to reduce half the pain is to avoid doing the operation in the trigger itself and instead use an Apex class as a trigger handler. Then your trigger handler can be declared 'with sharing' so that record access is enforced. But that still leaves the other half -- CRUD/FLS checks that need to be enforced manually. There is an [idea exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Lj8GAAS) request to auto-invoke CRUD/FLS which should make this easier.

The bottom line is that whether you need to respect an organization's security rules is a business logic question and not a question of whether you do your DML operation in a trigger or not. Implementation choices such as this cannot lift the requirement to respect user permissions.

Although you should create permission sets that contain all the necessary permissions for your users, but if the admin changes the user permissions or inadvertently assigns a user with a different permission set to your app, then your app needs to detect the violation and should error out the operation. In other words, even though your code might be setup so that CRUD/FLS is always true if the admin does what you expect, you still need to bulk up your code with perm checks in case the admin deviates -- at least if you are building managed packages. This rule applies regardless of what you do in a Apex trigger and what you do in an Apex class.

Comment: Thank you Robert for taking time to write this answer. I'm sure many people will benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are run in System context (My googling skills aren't bringing a sufficient link up so I can't prove this ATM but know it's true).  There is NO user interaction at all here and so no reason to protect against User tampering of data.

The permissions are designed so that Users cannot do something they shouldn't be able to.  Triggers work Independently from the user (Unless you specifically specify them to) and there is not any real reasons you would want them to.